# Understanding Ruby script for cassandra database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sinatra, cassandra

I am a Ruby novice. But due to some problem I have to handle the code as our ruby developer is not available. We are using cassandra database to get values from a Ruby (Sinatra) web service and put it into the Cassandra keyspace. But due to some problem , the data is failing to insert.

In the following code partners_daily , partner_monthly etc are column family (tables) in the stats keyspace(database).

```
if params and !partner_id.nil? and !activity_type.nil?
            {
                :partners_daily    => "#{partner_id}_#{activity_type}_#{success == 1 ? 'sucess' : "failure:#{failure_code}"}_#{time.year}_#{time.month}_#{time.day}",
                :partners_monthly  => "#{partner_id}_#{activity_type}_#{success == 1 ? 'sucess' : "failure:#{failure_code}"}_#{time.year}_#{time.month}",
                :partners_alltime  => "#{partner_id}_#{activity_type}_#{success == 1 ? 'sucess' : "failure:#{failure_code}"}",

                :channels_daily    => "#{channel_id}_#{activity_type}_#{success == 1 ? 'sucess' : "failure:#{failure_code}"}_#{time.year}_#{time.month}_#{time.day}",
                :channels_monthly  => "#{channel_id}_#{activity_type}_#{success == 1 ? 'sucess' : "failure:#{failure_code}"}_#{time.year}_#{time.month}",
                :channels_alltime  => "#{channel_id}_#{activity_type}_#{success == 1 ? 'sucess' : "failure:#{failure_code}"}",

                :countries_daily    => "#{country}_#{activity_type}_#{success == 1 ? 'sucess' : "failure:#{failure_code}"}_#{time.year}_#{time.month}_#{time.day}",
                :countries_monthly  => "#{country}_#{activity_type}_#{success == 1 ? 'sucess' : "failure:#{failure_code}"}_#{time.year}_#{time.month}",
                :countries_alltime  => "#{country}_#{activity_type}_#{success == 1 ? 'sucess' : "failure:#{failure_code}"}"
            }.each do |k,v| 
                stats.add(k, v, 1, 'count')
            end


            return "Activity stored in stats"
        end
    else
        return "Error: client headers missing"
    end
end

def count(table, key)

    require 'cassandra-cql' # requiring this at the top was leading to error: unconfigured columnfamily
    cqldb = CassandraCQL::Database.new('127.0.0.1:9160', {:keyspace => 'plystats'})

    query = "update partners_daily set count = ? where key = ?"#"update #{table} set count = count+1 where key = ?;"

    #return cqldb.execute(query, 0, 'sonia').inspect
    return query    

end
```

I want to know how the data inserting logic in it is being performed, and where ? Is it in `stats.add(k, v, 1, 'count')` ?

and is there any error in the inserting part because its failing.

Comment: there comes no error in the script, its just that values are not getting inserted into the database. But yeah when I right click the column family and select show 1000 rows.. an `error: Null` message pops up.

Comment: Yeah i guess.. but uncommenting it makes no difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to know how the data inserting logic in it is being performed, and where ? Is it in stats.add(k, v, 1, 'count') ?

Yes, that's where it should be happening. Between the `{}` are dictionary/hash values:

```
{
   :partners_daily => # …
}.each do |k,v|
```

A loop is started with the `each` method, and each entry is decomposed and put into `k` and `v`, the key in `k` and the value in `v`. For example, the first record in the hash is:

```
:partners_daily    => "#{partner_id}_#{activity_type}_#{success == 1 ? 'sucess' : "failure:#{failure_code}"}_#{time.year}_#{time.month}_#{time.day}",
```

This would then decompose within the `each` loop to:

```
k = :partners_daily
v =  # The result of
     "#{partner_id}_#{activity_type}_#{success == 1 ? 'sucess' : "failure:#{failure_code}"}_#{time.year}_#{time.month}_#{time.day}",
```

I don't now what the values are for `partner_id` etc, but making some up it'd look something like `"123_sales_sucess_2013_6_01"`

Notice there's a typo for the word `success` in there.

It's a bit confusing due to the multiple double quotes and braces, so I'd change this to:

```
[partner_id, activity_type, (success == 1 ? 'success' : "failure:#{failure_code}"), time.year, time.month, time.day].join("_")
```

But notice that there's a lot of repetition in there, so I'd change the whole hash to (at least):

```
success_string = success == 1 ?
                   'success' : 
                   "failure:#{failure_code}"

data = {
  :partners_daily    => [partner_id, activity_type,success_string,time.year,time.month,time.day].join("_"),
  :partners_monthly  => [partner_id,activity_type,success_string,time.year,time.month].join("_"),
  :partners_alltime  => [partner_id,activity_type,success_string].join("_"),

  :channels_daily    => [channel_id,activity_type,success_string,time.year,time.month,time.day].join("_"),
  :channels_monthly  => [channel_id,activity_type,success_string,time.year,time.month].join("_"),
  :channels_alltime  => [channel_id,activity_type,success_string].join("_"),

  :countries_daily    => [country,activity_type,success_string,time.year,time.month,time.day].join("_"),
  :countries_monthly  => [country,activity_type,success_string,time.year,time.month].join("_"),
  :countries_alltime  => [country,activity_type,success_string].join("_")
}

data.each do |k,v|
  # more code…
```

It starts to be easier to read and see the logic. Also, by putting the hash into the `data` variable instead of working on it immediately, it allows you to inspect it more easily, e.g.

```
warn "data = #{data.inspect}"
```

would output a representation of the data to the console, so at least you could get an idea of what the script is attempting to put in. At the top of this code, you could also add `warn "script = #{script.inspect}"` to check what the `script` object looks like.

If the `script` object is a Cassandra instance i.e. there's something like `script = Cassandra.new "blah", "blahblah"` that sets it up, then the `add` method is [this one](http://rubydoc.info/gems/cassandra/0.18.0/Cassandra%3aadd)

The signature given is `add(column_family, key, value, *columns_and_options)` but that doesn't seem to match the call you have:

```
stats.add(k, v, 1, 'count')
```

should (probably) be:

```
stats.add('count', k, v, 1)
```

In fact, I'm not even sure that the concatenation in the `data` hash should happen and maybe all of that should just be passed to `add`, but it's your data so I can't be sure.

Feel free to comment below and I'll update this.

---

Trying it in IRB to check it for syntax errors:

```
success = 1
# => 1
partner_id = 123
# => 123
activity_type = "something"
# => "something"
time = Time.now
# => 2013-06-05 11:17:50 0100
channel_id = 456
# => 456
country = "UK"
# => "UK"
success_string = success == 1 ?
                     'success' : 
                     "failure:#{failure_code}"
# => "success"

  data = {
      :partners_daily    => [partner_id, activity_type,success_string,time.year,time.month,time.day].join("_"),
      :partners_monthly  => [partner_id,activity_type,success_string,time.year,time.month].join("_"),
      :partners_alltime  => [partner_id,activity_type,success_string].join("_"),

      :channels_daily    => [channel_id,activity_type,success_string,time.year,time.month,time.day].join("_"),
      :channels_monthly  => [channel_id,activity_type,success_string,time.year,time.month].join("_"),
      :channels_alltime  => [channel_id,activity_type,success_string].join("_"),

      :countries_daily    => [country,activity_type,success_string,time.year,time.month,time.day].join("_"),
      :countries_monthly  => [country,activity_type,success_string,time.year,time.month].join("_"),
      :countries_alltime  => [country,activity_type,success_string].join("_")
  }
# => {:partners_daily=>"123_something_success_2013_6_5", :partners_monthly=>"123_something_success_2013_6", :partners_alltime=>"123_something_success", :channels_daily=>"456_something_success_2013_6_5", :channels_monthly=>"456_something_success_2013_6", :channels_alltime=>"456_something_success", :countries_daily=>"UK_something_success_2013_6_5", :countries_monthly=>"UK_something_success_2013_6", :countries_alltime=>"UK_something_success"}
```

Comment: Hey iain .. thanks a lot buddy. This is just great help. You simplified things for me really well.

Comment: I think `stats.add(k, v, 1, 'count')` will remain like this because we have keyspaces in db of the same name as partners_daily,partners_monthly,..so on. +

Comment: @RyanMalhotra Glad I could be of some help.

Comment: But doing this `data = {#code..}
data.each do |k,v|`
gives  syntax error, unexpected '\n', expecting tASSOC

Comment: @RyanMalhotra there's a typo, a missing comma in the first line of data assignment. Use the "edited" link to see it.

Comment: Yeah buddy, I noticed and corrected it already, still getting the  syntax error, unexpected '\n', expecting tASSOC.

Comment: @RyanMalhotra If I plug in some fake values I don't get a syntax error. I added it to the answer, maybe it'll help you track down where it's coming from.